# Reading directly from a URL in Java

Tags: java, html, url, web

When I print the contents of http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_3?rh=n%3A172282&page=1, I  see different HTML than what's displayed when utilizing the "View Source" feature in my browser (Chrome, in my case, though I don't think the exact browser matters). For example, the div with id "result_10" from the aforementioned URL appears like this in one's browser:

```
<div id="result_10" class="rsltGrid prod" name="B007I5JT4S">
```

But when printing the same web page contents with Java's `java.net.URL` utility, the same div appears like this:

```
<div class="result product" id="result_10" name="B007I5JT4S">
```

This is just one of the many differences in identifiers and page structure between the HTML produced by programmatically reading this page and using a browser. I'm not sure if this stems from some sort of URL resolution issue or something entirely different.

How can I acquire the same page content I see in my browser from a Java app?

Here's the function I've been using to read URLs, with "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_3?rh=n%3A172282&page=1" being the argument in question.

```
public static void printWebPageContents(String url) throws IOException {
    URL specifiedUrl = new URL(url);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(specifiedUrl.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);

    in.close();
}
```

Don't hesitate to let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: Have you considered that perhaps they do some sort of User Agent detection? (in which case it'd be a matter of spoofing it).

Comment: *"Don't hesitate to let me know if any clarification is needed."*  What is your question?

Comment: You know how a website will look one way on your computer, and another way on your phone? It's like that.

Comment: @AndrewThompson How can I acquire the same page content I see in my browser from a Java app?

Comment: *"How can I acquire the same page content I see in my browser from a Java app?"*  a) Edit that into the ..question. b) But please clarify - which browser?  You say above WTE 'browser does not matter', but if you inspect the source delivered to ***each*** browser, you might be surprised by the differences.

Comment: You may be right - I didn't think there would be much variation between browsers. I'm just trying to write a web scraper for this URL - would you suggest spoofing the user agent or taking a different approach? I ask because the the content I acquire programmatically is poorly organized and difficult to parse compared to what's presented in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be surprised if it had to do with your [User Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent_string#User_agent_identification).  I don't know what the default is for `URL.openStream`, but I doubt it's the same as Chrome.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that different user agents are provided with different content. Is there an easy way to acquire the same page content that I see in Chrome?

Comment: @AlexWood Maybe.  Try spoofing the chrome user agent. It's up to amazon.com to decide what content they serve you.  It might not only be based on your agent.

Comment: there may also be Ajax or other javascripty goodness going on there, modifying tags and adding content.