# In Jsoup, how do I connect and read a page with a URL like "https://rateyourmusic.com/film/%E4%B9%B1"?

Tags: java, character-encoding, jsoup

Sorry for having to put the URL in the Title, but I didn't know how to describe it.

Anyway... I have a file that contains the following URLs:

```
https://rateyourmusic.com/film/%E7%A0%82%E3%81%AE%E5%A5%B3
https://rateyourmusic.com/film/%E7%94%9F%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B
https://rateyourmusic.com/film/%E4%B9%B1
https://rateyourmusic.com/film/%E7%BE%85%E7%94%9F%E9%96%80
```

I wanted to write a program in Java, using Jsoup, that would open those URLs and gather some information. Here's the program:

```
public class RymUrlTest {
    public static void main(String args[]){     
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new FileReader("list.txt")));

            String line="";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Document d = Jsoup.connect(line).timeout(0).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36").get();
            }           
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://rateyourmusic.com/film/ç ?ã?®å¥³
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:435)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:446)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
    at RymUrlTest.main(RymUrlTest.java:15)
```

Would anyone know how to make Jsoup recognize the URLs properly?

Even when I try using URLEncoder.encode, i still get an error.

Answer (score 2):

the urls that you are hitting is doint a 302 redirect to another url which is the one giving you an error. Teh raw response headers form the first URL in your list in the question are:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 05 Dec 2013 05:15:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 317
Location: http://rateyourmusic.com/film/ç ã®å¥³
Mime-Version: 1.0
X-Firefox-Spdy: 2
```

Make sure that you have JSOUP configured to follow redirects and handle the URLs in UTF-8 charset.

Also try to open the URLs in firefox and gather the request headers which it sends. Use those request headers in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

First verify `line` contains the value you expect, and doesn't have a trailing newline or carriage return. The top of your question says https, but the log says http.

Try converting the %E4 characters to Unicode instead. Use URLEncoder.decode instead and convert it to a plain String, which is UTF by default. Then pass that instead.

If that doesn't work, try [reading the page manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943557/reading-directly-from-a-url-in-java) using URL and InputStreams into a String, then call `JSoup.parse(string)`. http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can parse the url before giving it to Jsoup:

```
public static void main(String args[]){     
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new FileReader("list.txt")));
        final Matcher WHITESPACE_REMOVER = Pattern.compile("\\s+").matcher("");

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line = WHITESPACE_REMOVER.reset(line).replaceAll("%20");
            String url = URI.create(line).toASCIIString();
            Document d = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36").get();
        }           
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```